# Parse to string a JS function as an Object value

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

Looking for a solution on parsing to string a JS function as an Object value.
All ideas are welcomed!

The final result would be a string config that i need to pass to a 3-rd party library (this is just a small part).

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-goldberg-scsvyq?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { TEST } from "./config";

function objToString(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((cstring, [key, value]) => {
    // creates a string in the format 'key: value, key2: value2, etc...'
    return cstring !== "" ? `${cstring}, ${key}: ${value}` : `${key}: ${value}`;
  }, "");
}

export default function App() {
  let configString = objToString({
    onChangeBrand: function () {
      const test = TEST.Success;

      return test;
    }
  });

  configString = `var configString = {
    ${configString}
  }`;

  console.log(configString);

  return <p>configObj = `{configString}`</p>;
}
```

**Current output**

```
var configString = {
    onChangeBrand: function () {
      const test = _config.TEST.Success;
      return test;
    }
  }
```

**Desired output**

```
var configString = {
    onChangeBrand: function () {
      const test = "success";
      return test;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you meant the desirered output to return variable `test` instead of string `"success"`

Comment: Yes you're right! Edited

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but with a small change in onChangeBrand and the function call of aciConfig i think i've got your desired output:

```
import { TEST } from "./config";

function objToString(obj) {
 return Object.entries(obj).reduce((cstring, [key, value]) => {
 // creates a string in the format 'key: value, key2: value2, etc...'
   return cstring !== "" ? `${cstring}, ${key}: ${value}` : `${key}: ${value}`;
   }, "");
 }

export default function App() {
  const fun = () => {
    const test = TEST.Success;
    return test;
  };
  const vari = TEST;
  const aciConfig = (v) => {
    return {
      onChangeBrand: function () {
        const ss = v.Success.toString();
        const rr = fun();
        return {ss, rr}
      }
    };
  };
  let configObj = aciConfig(vari).onChangeBrand()
  let configString = objToString(configObj);

  console.log(typeof configObj.ss)
  console.log(configObj.ss)

  configString = `var configString = {
    ${configString}
  }`;

  console.log(configString);

  return <p>configObj = `{configString}`</p>;
}
```